# MySQL Datetime in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

I'm working on a chart from MySQL, it worked fine as a linechart but when I changed to annotationchart it gave me the following error due to it needing a date/time, I changed the type to datetime (was string) and still have the error.

```
Type mismatch. Value 2014-07-23 19:03:16 does not match type datetime
```

Original Code

```
 <?php
        $con=mysql_connect("ip","user","pass") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
        mysql_select_db("db", $con); 

        $sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db.table");

        $data = array (
      'cols' => array( 
        array('id' => 'date', 'label' => 'date', 'type' => 'datetime'), 
        array('id' => 'Temp', 'label' => 'Temp', 'type' => 'number'), 
        array('id' => 'Humid', 'label' => 'Humid', 'type' => 'number')
    ),
    'rows' => array()
);

while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth))
    // array nesting is complex owing to to google charts api
    array_push($data['rows'], array('c' => array(
        array('v' => $res['TIME']), 
        array('v' => $res['TEMP']), 
        array('v' => $res['HUMID'])
    )));

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['annotationchart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
            var bar_chart_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);
        var options = {
          title: 'Weather Station'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(bar_chart_data, options);
      }
    </script>
</head>
            <body>
                <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "datetime" data type requires a very specific syntax for data input.  When using JSON, the data should be constructed as a string in this format: `'Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)'`, where all options after `month` are optional (default is `1` for `day` and `0` for all others) and `month` is zero-indexed (so January is `0` not `1`).

You can convert your date times like this:

```
while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    // assumes dates are patterned 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'
    preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/', $res['TIME'], $match);
    $year = (int) $match[1];
    $month = (int) $match[2] - 1; // convert to zero-index to match javascript's dates
    $day = (int) $match[3];
    $hours = (int) $match[4];
    $minutes = (int) $match[5];
    $seconds = (int) $match[6];
    array_push($data['rows'], array('c' => array(
        array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)"), 
        array('v' => $res['TEMP']), 
        array('v' => $res['HUMID'])
    )));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @asgallant , much closer but I'm still getting a new error

`Type mismatch. Value Date(0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0) does not match type datetime`

All I've done is add `while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth))` to the top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Asgallant and much fiddling the following code fixed all my problems

```
    array('v' => 'Date(' . date('Y,n,d,H,i,s', strtotime($res['TIME'])).')'), 
    array('v' => floatval($res['TEMP'])), 
    array('v' => floatval($res['HUMID']))
```

I found a streamlined way to convert MySQL Datetime to javascript using the PHP Date function and although the Temp and Humid values were stored as Decimals in MySQL, javascript didn't like it so I used floatval to make those work also. Now I have a happy, working Annotation Chart!

Comment: Those dates will be off by 1 month (because javascript uses a zero-based index for months), which is why you need to break your dates out like I did in my answer.

Comment: They seem to be fine at the moment?

Comment: Check the dates in your chart against the database, you will find they are off by 1 month. Ex: `'Date(' . date('Y,n,d,H,i,s', strtotime('January 1, 2014')).')'` becomes `'Date(2014,1,1,0,0,0)'` which (after being parsed into a javascript Date object) becomes `February 1, 2014`.

Comment: Ahh sorry yeah I see what you mean, your code doesn't work though? I just get `Type mismatch. Value Date(0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0) does not match type datetime` the date isn't making it in to be converted.

Comment: If the pattern does not match, then you need to adjust it for your date format.  I assumed the format was `'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'`, per the code comments.

Comment: `array('v' => 'Date(' . date('Y,n,d,H,i,s', strtotime ( '-1 month' , strtotime ($res['TIME']) ) ).')'), `

This seems to be working?

Comment: What happens with that code when you use `March 1, 2014`?  I suspect that you will get `January 28, 2014`, because the `+/- month` modifier is adding or subtracting multiples of 31 days.  I don't believe that there is any formatting option you can use for PHP dates that will return the correct format - or at least if there is one, I have never seen anyone post an example of it.

Comment: The problem I'm having with your code is not the date format, but that it doesn't work. If I change to this

`preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/', $res['TIME'],$match);`

From this

`$match = preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/', $res['TIME']);`

I get the date, but only one value and the temp/humid come back as null.

`"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 6, 31, 14, 30, 9)"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}]});`

Comment: You're right, I had the wrong syntax for `preg_match`.  This should not have any effect on the temp and humid values, though.  I created a test case that shows the code working fine: http://ideone.com/rUA3da

Comment: How would I incorporate that back into my original code, I'm using the following to loop through the database results, as can be seen in the original post. Thanks for your help.

`while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth))`

Comment: Just wrap the code in the while loop.  I updated my answer with this.