# MYSQL Datetime to JSON to Google Charts

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to use the Google Chart function: hAxis: {format: 'MMM, d,Y'} but I can't get it to work. And I belive it has to do with that I'm doing the conversion, from my Mysql DB to JSON wrong.

So, how can I do this in the right manner (in this example I'm just trying to view the "Days" at the x-axis). Here is what i got so far, and thanks to [MySQL Datetime in Google Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929767/mysql-datetime-in-google-chart).

In other words, I would like the hAxis function to extract the days. So what is shown under the x-axis will only be the days.

For clarification purpose I add a picture how it looks like right now.
[image]

```
$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
array('label' => 'Time', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Temperature', 'type' => 'number')
);

$sql="SELECT * FROM LOG_TABLE ORDER BY ID";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

/* Extract the information from $result */
foreach($result as $r) 
{
  // This conversion because JSON doesen't take Date Object
  // assumes dates are patterned 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'
  preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/', $r["TIME"], $match);
  $year = (int) $match[1];
  $month = (int) $match[2] - 1; // convert to zero-index to match javascript's dates
  $day = (int) $match[3];
  $hours = (int) $match[4];
  $minutes = (int) $match[5];
  $seconds = (int) $match[6];

  $temp = array();
  $temp[] = array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)");
  $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $r['TEMPERATURE']);
  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

And here the rest:

```
// Load the Visualization API and the chart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
  var options = {
       title: 'Temperature Variation',
       legend: { position: 'bottom' },
      hAxis: {format: 'd'},
      width: 800,
      height: 600
    };
  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  // Do not forget to check your div ID
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: and what is your actual problem? what happens and what should be happening?

Comment: `array('label' => 'Time', 'type' => 'string')`, this should probably have datetime as the type. Unclear what your issue is though

Comment: Beat - I've tried to clarify the above post.
rjdown - That will give me an error: c[Ie] is not a function×